# Facebook application url and comment box

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-comments

I have multiple application on Facebook suddenly I got this issue without any code change.

I have a facebook comment plugin with href of the application URL but it is not working correctly as I can't expand or see any comment, also moderate interface is not visible in some applications

[image]

My meta s are

[image] "Sorry I had to null the data"

Any idea what is the problem, and how to fix this, I could not find anything!

Here is more screen shots

NORMAL USER

[image]

ADMIN USER

[image]

Comment: Does the web/javascript console of your browser display any errors?

Comment: Not sure it will help but it's in the docs: "You can choose to specify either `fb:app_id` or `fb:admins`, but not both."

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work? Have you checked the browser cache?

Comment: I did try both ways with one or both fb:app_id or fb:admins, this bug is exists on chrome, firefox and IE ...